# I am looking for an adjective to describe "painful reality"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am wondering which adjective could describe something is unexpectedly tough but pretty fair (I have "neutral" attitudes toward it).

For example:

```
I found the final exam was so ***. I really should have worked harder.
```

Edit: I also want to use this adjective formally, like:

```
Although the test is a fair game, I have never thought it could be so tough.
```

Edit: I am so sorry for “nitpicking”. I would use this word in the emails to the professor who made that test, so I want to be as neutral and polite as I can.

Comment: "The exam was hell?" This partially fits your requirement.

Comment: @Neptunian Hmmm, I may want to be more formal. Like "Although the test is a fair game, I never thought it could be so tough". Thank you though!

Comment: You should update your question to mention you want a more formal adjective.

Comment: I can only think of non-formal words. "The test was so brutal."

Comment: @Neptunian Haha me too. I want to use it in emails to my professor, so you see :)

Comment: @JayWong Why can't you use "it was **unexpectedly difficult**", or "**more difficult than expected**"?

Comment: @Rathony Thank you, I just think they are kinda "agressive". I want to use this word in emails to the professor who made that test.

Comment: What makes you think those expressions are aggressive?

Comment: @Rathony "Unexpectedly", it implies I may think the test is unfair (harder than what I was told)

Comment: Your question clearly states that it was unexpectedly tough. Your question is not clear then. Have you ever taken any exam that is not fair to everybody?

Comment: @Rathony Sorry for the question description. Yes it was unexpectedly tough, but I try to be more implicit. This word tells even though the exam is "unexpectedly hard", I would agree it is a really good test.

Comment: Painful reality? How about **toothache**?

Comment: Professors usually like to hear/believe that their tests are "challenging" or "demanding."

Comment: @PapaPoule Yeah, "challenging" fits. What does "demanding" mean in this case?

Comment: @HotLicks "toothache" is so cute, thank you! I would remember that.

Comment: "Demanding" would probably work better to describe the professor: "The demanding professor always gave challenging exams."

Comment: The exam was demanding but straightforward.

Comment: @PapaPoule Thank you! It really makes sense for me.

Comment: @Faemu Thank you so much, I really admire this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure this fits exactly, but you could try *[eye-opener](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eye+opener)*:-

> A startling or shocking revelation. [American Heritage Dictionary]

Your example sentence would then read:-

> I found the final exam a real *eye-opener*.

Comment: Thank you Brian, eye-opener really stresses out the "unexpectedly", but it implies that I may have negative attitudes toward the object. Do you know other words which are more neutral?

Comment: @Jay Wong Using eye-opener means you now realize how over-confident you were, how much you didn't understand and how much more you should have studied.  Any professor would be happy to hear that his exam opened the eyes of a student. It is a positive statement about the exam.

Comment: @ab2   Thank you so much! This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The final exam was `taxing`

taxing: physically or mentally demanding